# Propagatable vs propagable?

Tags: orthography

`propagatable` vs `propagable`

Which one is correct? I've seen both in usage.

Comment: In C19 it was [almost always the shorter form](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=propagatable%2Cpropagable&year_start=1800&year_end=1900&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpropagatable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpropagable%3B%2Cc0) - and that's the only one listed in the full OED. But [**propagatable** has been steadily gaining traction through C20](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=propagatable%2Cpropagable&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpropagatable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpropagable%3B%2Cc0), and is now equally common.

Comment: (I believe "Which is correct?" is a meaningless question in such contexts.)

Comment: The problem is that most people probably have better luck pronouncing and understanding "propagatable" than "propagable", since the former is simply adding "able" to "propagate".  I wouldn't necessarily recommend using "propagatable", but I'd strongly discourage using "propagable".  But probably best to avoid both and phrase things a different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [*propagable*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/propagable) appears in dictionaries, it might be considered more useful and appropriate in formal or technical writing:

> adjective
>
> capable of being propagated
>
> <sub>Collins Dictionary</sub>

It is derived directly from the Latin *propago* and the suffix [-able](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-able):

> 1560s, "to cause to multiply,"
>   from Latin *propagatus*, past participle
>   of *propagare* "to set forward, extend, procreate"
>   (see [propagation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=propagation&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> mid-15c., from Old French *propagacion* "offshoot, offspring" (13c.) and
>   directly from Latin *propagationem* (nominative *propagatio*) "a
>   propagation, extension, enlargement," noun of action
>   from past
>   participle stem of *propagare* "set forward, extend, spread, increase;
>   multiply plants by layers, breed,"
>   from ***propago*** (genitive propaginis) "that which propagates, offspring,"
>   from *pro*- "forth" (see pro-) +
>   *pag-, root of *pangere* "to fasten" (see pact).
>
> <sub>etymonline.com **emphasis** added</sub>

*[Propagatable](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=propagatable%2Cpropagable&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpropagatable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpropagable%3B%2Cc0)* is a back formation from the English *[propagate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/propagate)*, and for informal or colloquial speech, the audible clue of *propagate* may help less educated listeners discern the meaning. *Propagatable* has become as *[recognizable](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=propagatable%2Cpropagable&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpropagatable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpropagable%3B%2Cc0)* as the equally rare *propagable*:

[image]

<sub>Image from Google Books</sub>

Comment: Try pronouncing "propagable" three times fast.

Comment: @HotLicks, thanks for the detailed explanation. Indeed, both are irritating to pronounce. The question originates from deciding which form should be used for naming a variable in a software system. I think I'll reason to using `propagable` for it's found in the English Dictionary (unlike `propagatabla`) and it's composed of less characters. Length it's a big deal for us, lazy programmers.

Comment: @razvan -"Indeed, both are irritating to pronounce."  Hence my suggestion to find a different term.

Comment: LOL! Propagable, propagable,propagable! What's so difficult, @HotLicks ;-) It's just  an alveolar approximant between two voiceless bilabial stops  followed by a voiced velar stop and a voiced bilabial stop. All those schwas make it a synch!